# Are there Rules for 'Splitting' Feynman Diagrams?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

I was talking with a mathematician colleague and promised to look up a concept in QFT for them but am not sure what they were referring to.  They were referring to rules named after two people (both of them having names beginning with a c or a k by the sound of it) which can be used to 'split up' Feynman diagrams such that you end up resolving the path integral into a complex and a real part or something along those lines.  I am not sure what they mean by this or if they are referring to splitting functions.

Obviously, if I search for rules and Feynman diagrams, I just get information on the Feynman rules.

Comment: perhabs you are looking for something like this? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/303921/

Comment: Cutkosky cutting rules (isn't the alliteration a funny coincidence!)

Comment: (But maybe we wouldn't have called them cutting rules if he'd had another name)

Comment: Sounds a bit like the BCFW recursion relations?

Comment: Yes, it's the Cutkosky rules, it sounded like two names the way she said 'Cutkosky cutting'.